# Prove that the Hilbert cube is totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis

According to my book, the Hilbert cube $\cal{H}$ is the collection of all real sequences $x = x_n$ with $\|x_n\| \leq 1$ for $n = 1, 2, ...$. The metric difined on $\cal{H}$ I need to use in this context is 
$$ d(x, y) = \sum^\infty_ {n=1} 2^{-n}\|x_n - y_n\|.$$
In another exercise I proved that $\cal{H}$ is seperable, so maybe I need to use that here. I have no clue for as how to even start this prove.

Comment: The notation $H^\infty$ is often used for the [Hardy space of bounded analytical functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space). I changed it to $\cal{H}$ to avoid misunderstanding if you dont mind.

Comment: Hint: the tail end of this summation, $\sum_{n=k}^\infty 2^{-n} |x_n - y_n|$, is bounded by $2^{-k + 1}$. Now if you need to cover your Hilbert cube with sets of size $\epsilon$, first choose $k$ large enough that $2^{-k + 1} < \epsilon/2$, and focus on bounding the first $k-1$ terms.